# What are the various constructs that one could use to break out of an "always" block in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, fpga, xilinx

For instance in this thread - [How to NOT use while() loops in verilog (for synthesis)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2361024/how-to-not-use-while-loops-in-verilog-for-synthesis), Brian Carlton mentions that instead of using for and while loops in Verilog, one should use an `always` loop. I was wondering what are the ways to break out of an iteration if a particular condition is satisfied. I was wondering if the following could be used :

always @ (posedge clk or var == 3)`

Where `var` is a variable in the module or block?

For instance, how would I convert the following code into something which can be synthesized by XST.

```
    //******************************************************
//Check whether randp is prime or not
//******************************************************
for(i = 0; i < 100; i = i+1)
begin
    assign PRIME_CHECK = randp;
    assign sqroot = PRIME_CHECKED;
for(i = 0 ; i <= sqroot ; i=i+1)
    begin
        if((sqroot%i) == 0)
        begin
            break;
        end
    end
    break;
    randp = RANDP;
end
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to *break out* of `always` block. You are declaring the existence of a process that is *always* there. Hardware cannot be dynamically created or destroyed. What you can do is wrap the code around a condition and branch around it. But if you are writing synthesizable code, the `always` block must *always* follow the coding rules for sequential or combinational logic.

BTW `var` is a reserved keyword in SystemVerilog, so don't use it.

--Updated--
Now that you have added the software code you want translated to hardware, that is a different question. Before you can break out of this loop, you need to partition the loop into clock cycles of a state machine. Then a break out of a loop becomes a jump in your state machine.

Comment: So if I wanted to replace a while loop, could I use `(@posedge clk or a == 2) begin` ?

Comment: You need to show the while loop you are trying to recreate. @(expession) is just a statement inside the loop. And `(@posedge clk or a == 2)`, although legal syntax, makes no sense. it means _block the the current process until either clk goes from 0 to 1, OR until the result of the expression a==2 has any change_. Certainly not synthesizable to hardware